# Git with multiple accounts gives same username while doing ssh

Tags: git, github, ssh, accounts, multiple-users

I have 2 git accounts on my mac for which I have 2 sets of public and private keys.
 I have a config file in /.ssh to manage those accounts, which looks like this:

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host github-user2
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_user2
```

Code from these accounts are to be pushed to 2 different remote repositories for which I set their different remotes in their respective directories using following command:

```
git remote add origin github.com:xyz_user/abc.git
git remote add origin github-user2:pqr_user/def.git
```

I am successfully able to push to these repos from both accounts.

When I use ssh,

```
ssh-add -l
```

shows private keys for both of the accounts added.
But

```
ssh -T github.com
ssh -T github-user2
```

both gives the following message:

```
"Hi user2! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access."
```

1 more thing that I have noticed, even If there is no key listed with " ssh-add -l"

```
ssh -T github.com & ssh -T github-user2 provide successful authenticate message.
```

How will I differentiate between both the accounts while making ssh connection?
Where does ssh -T authenticate from?

Answer (score 1):

> How will I differentiate between both the accounts while making ssh connection?

You won't really: both public keys have been registered in the same GitHub account, so as far as GitHub is concerned, both ssh authenticate you as 'user2'.

> Where does ssh -T authenticate from?

It is looking in the [ssh keys section](https://github.com/settings/ssh) of your [Account profile](https://github.com/settings/profile).
Both public keys are registered there, as explained in the [GitHub help page on "Generating SSH Keys"](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys).

Comment: Hey Von, thanks for replying. But, both the public keys are registered in different GitHub account.

Comment: @Manu Is it possible that the public keys are *duplicated* in both GitHub accounts?

Comment: @Manu also, see here (https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996) an example of a successful two-accounts ssh setup.

Comment: Unfortunately both the public keys are different :(

Comment: @Manu just to check, can you try your `ssh -T github.com` from a different computer, to see if still 'User2' is mentioned?

Comment: Although I am able to push to both accounts successfully. I want to know, why is ssh -T github.com and ssh -T github-user2 resulting in same message ?

Comment: @Manu they shouldn't be, since the config file reference two different private keys, with two public keys registered in two different GitHub accounts. Try, just in case, to check `git config user.name` and `git config user.email`.